# toggle javascript function

Tags: javascript, toggle, togglebutton

I'm using this code to start a log file :

```
function startTail(str) {
if (str== "stop") {
stopTail();
} else {
t= setTimeout("getLog()",1000);
}
}
```

This is called using :

```
<button id="start" onclick="getLog('start');">
```

and stopped using :

```
<button id="stop" onclick="getLog('stop');">
```

Is there anyway I can change this to one button that will toggle start / stop ?

Comment: There you go http://codepen.io/joe/pen/ezdhH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<button id="start" value="Toggle Log" onclick="getLog('start', this);">

function startTail(str, element) {
    if (str == "stop") {
        stopTail();
        element.setAttribute('onclick', "getLog('start', this);");
    } else {
        element.setAttribute('onclick', "getLog('stop', this);");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this starts the log, but seems to stop it straight way. This is the log script I'm using : http://commavee.com/2007/04/13/ajax-logfile-tailer-viewer/

Comment: Thanks, I had to update another function that was calling startTail() to startTail(str, element) !

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
var flag = false;
function startTail() {
 if (flag)
  {
    stopTail();
    document.getElementById('start').value = "Start";
    flag = false;
  }
 else 
  {
    t= setTimeout("getLog()",1000);
    flag = true;
    document.getElementById('start').value = "Stop";
  }
}

<button id="start" onclick="startTail();" value="Start">
```

Comment: This seems to do the same as the above. starts but then stops.